# Confused about calculating the area under the curve

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

What is the area under the curve of the following function?

$f(x) = x² + 2x -3$

$x=-4$

$x=2$

Please, I'd like to see an image.

Here is the graphic:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oe0ja17spg

Comment: Area over what interval? And area or signed area.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla I didn't understand you because I'm new in calculus, but please see my edit.

Comment: @Eimi He means, does the area under the $x$-axis count as negative or positive?

Comment: Usually areas are considered positive. One can substract an area from another area, but the substracted area itself is still positive. In this case you have to add all areas like $\color{blue}{\texttt{Khallil}}$  has done it.

Comment: @Eimi Which things ?

Comment: @calculus I don't understand why daryakhosrotash included the s2 area. I thought that integrals define the area *under* the curve, not inside as he did.

Comment: @Eimi Khallil has calculated the area between the x-axis and the function f(x). Darya calculate the difference between the two areas above the x-axis and the area below the x-axis. A question: What is the word by word question ?

Answer (score 3):

The area enclosed between the $x$ axis and $f(x) = x^2 + 2x - 3$ over $\left[-4, 2 \right]$ is given by: $$ A = \int_{-4}^{-3} f(x) \text{ d}x + \left| \ \int_{-3}^{1} f(x) \text{ d}x \ \right| + \int_{1}^{2} f(x) \text{ d}x $$ since the sign of the integral over $\left[ -3, 1 \right]$ is negative.

---

> As a small addendum, consider the following integral $$ \int_{a}^{b} \left| f(x) \right| \text{ d}x $$ supposing that $f(x) \leqslant 0$ over some interval $[c,d] \subset [a,b]$ and non-negative elsewhere $$\begin{aligned} \implies  \int_{a}^{b} \left| f(x) \right| \text{ d}x & = \int_{a}^{c} f(x) \cdot \underbrace{\mathrm{sgn}(f(x))}_{+1} \text{ d}x + \int_{c}^{d} f(x) \cdot \underbrace{\mathrm{sgn}(f(x))}_{-1} \text{ d}x + \int_{d}^{b} f(x) \cdot \underbrace{\mathrm{sgn}(f(x))}_{+1} \text{ d}x \\ & = \int_{a}^{c} f(x) \text{ d}x - \underbrace{\int_{c}^{d} f(x) \text{ d}x}_{\text{Which is negative}} + \int_{d}^{b} f(x) \text{ d}x \\ & = A \end{aligned} $$ using $\left| f(x) \right| = f(x) \cdot \mathrm{sgn}(f(x)) $ on the respective domains over which we're integrating.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$$ area=s_1+|s_2|+s_3=\\\int_{-4}^{-3} (x^2+2x-3)dx +\\ |\int_{-3}^{1} (x^2+2x-3)dx |+\\\int_{1}^{2} (x^2+2x-3)dx$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand why you include the s2 area. I thought that integrals define the area **under** the curve. The s2 area is "inside" the curve.

Comment: Integrals define the signed area between the curve and the x axis. "Under the curve" only applies when the function is above the curve. When it's below it's more of "above the curve". Signed area means that if the area is below the x axis it is considered negative, and thus subtracted from your total area.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Thank you so much, if you add an answer explaining this, I'd vote for you.

Comment: maybe ...it make a sense .$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} sinx dx =0 $$ but area between $f(x)=sin x $ and x-axis given by : $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(x)| dx=\\ \int_{0}^{2\pi} |sinx |dx =\\ \int_{0}^{\pi} sinx dx +|\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} sinx dx |=2+2=4 $$